# Can I broadcast bluetooth low energy 20 KB data every 5 seconds from Android/iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, broadcast, beacon

I know there are some simulator apps for android to simulate BLE beacons like iBeacon, eddystone, etc...
but, I think these beacon standards can only transfer like 1 kilobyte or so, am I right?

I want to be able to broadcast 10-20 KiloByte data every 5 seconds from two or more smartphones, and then they must be able to scan each others broadcasts and so read each others data.

Is there any library or native API or something?

Comment: There is no way you can broadcast that much data. Advertising packets are very small. Even a single attribute update when you are connected is limited to about 60 bytes.

Comment: Then how BLE works with audio headphones? Audio need to be transferred at hundreds of kilobytes of speed. Doesn't a phone send 100+ KB per second to the air so a headphone can catch the audio data signal? And as I know BLE speed really can be 100 KBps.

Comment: Audio streams are passed over legacy Bluetooth protocols, not BLE GATT. Also, the data rate you can achieve with a connection is different to what a peripheral can broadcast. You can also use L2Cap for brother throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The length of each packet transmitted by Bluetooth is 20 bytes. According to calculation, the data transmitted in 5s is approximately equal to 5kb, so it is necessary to apply for MTU expansion from Bluetooth
But it depends on the maximum expansion supported by the device

```
mBluetoothGatt.requestMtu(512);
```

Comment: Then how BLE works with audio headphones? Audio need to be transferred at hundreds of kilobytes of speed. Doesn't a phone send 100+ KB per second to the air so a headphone can catch the audio data signal? And as I know BLE speed really can be 100 KBps.

Comment: Broadcasting / Advertising is a particular concept which use the three advertising channels to repeatedly broadcast a pre-defined message, which any "observer" can receive. This is very limited, at least in the non-latest Bluetooth spec. If you connect however to the device, you get a point-to-point connection and now you can suddenly send up to 1.4 Mbps in optimal cases.

Comment: Yes, it is, ideally, achievable. You need to determine whether the device supports MCU processing speed.
If you use ble + audio format, it is recommended to use ADPCM or opus format for better audio quality after decoding.
Of course, you can also use HFP in A2DP for audio interaction